# A function with a bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose there exist $\delta$, $M$ two positive real numbers.
We have a function $f$ that satisfies the following :
$f(0)=0$ , $M<\frac{f(x)}{x}, (x\ne0)$. and $|f'(x))|<\delta$.
Can we have a function $f$ such that : $M>\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M > \delta$, and take $x > 0$ such that $M < f(x)/x$, or equivalently, $f(x) > Mx$. By the mean value theorem, there is a point $c \in (0, x)$ such that $f'(c) > (Mx - 0)/(x - 0) = M$.

Thus $M < \delta$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.